# Duda consulta SQL que retorne la edad del dueño y autor de un libro

Tags: mysql, sql

i alguien pudiera ayudarme con esta consulta SQL, la misma debe devolver la edad del dueño de cada libro y la edad del autor. Gracias de antemano al que pueda colaborar.

```
table people id primary key, 
    name string, 
    age integer,

table books id primary key, 
    title string, 
    owner_id integer reference people(id), -- foreign key a la tabla personas (el dueño del libro) 
    author_id integer reference people(id), -- foreign key a la tabla personas (el autor del libro)
```

Con esta consulta devuelvo título y edad del creador pero no se como devolver también la edad del autor.

```
Select title, age AS owner_age FROM people, books Where people.id=books.owner_id
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La tercera es la vencida?

Comment: Muchas gracias, gracias a su ayuda resolvi, la consulta quda asi:                                        SELECT title, o.age AS owner_age, a.age AS author_age FROM books INNER JOIN  people AS o ON o.id=books.owner_id
INNER JOIN people AS a ON a.id=books.author_id

Answer (score 1):

Primero que nada, no usar joins en sql es algo ya muy antiguo (lo que se llamaba joins implicitos, que es como lo escribiste vos).

Así que vamos a arreglar eso... porque viendo eso, nos vamos a dar cuenta de algo...

```
Select title, age AS owner_age FROM people inner join books on people.id=books.owner_id
```

Ahora.. tenemos un problema.. porque necesitamos unir de vuelta a la tabla people, para obtener otra persona mas, que es el autor...

Asi que, nada mejor que agregar otro join a people, de vuelta, y traer de ahí la otra edad...

```
Select 
    b.title, 
    p.age AS owner_age,
    a.age as edad_del_autor
FROM people as p 
    inner join books as b on people.id=books.owner_id
    inner join people as a on books.author_id = people.id
```

Comment: hola, muchas gracias!! gracias a su ayuda ya resolvi, la consulta queda asi:           SELECT title, o.age AS owner_age, a.age AS author_age FROM books INNER JOIN  people AS o ON o.id=books.owner_id
INNER JOIN people AS a ON a.id=books.author_id